# How to introduce spell checker in Microsoft Office Communicator

Tags: office-2007

I type fast and make a lot of typos. All this is in forums and chat gets ignored but in office on Microsoft Communicator, I make a lot of mistakes. So I'm making a spell checker. Right now I'm testing it, but I want to know how can I associate my spell checker with Communicator.

Comment: Office Communicator doesn't natively support Spell Checking, maybe in a future version. But you could try and customize Office Communicator to add this yourself, which more information can be found [here][1]. But even then I think it still may be a uphill battle and may not even be possible with the limits they put on customization. [1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963963%28office.12%29.aspx